# iOS 10 and setting custom font for attributed text

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I've ported my app to XCode 8 and Swift 3 language syntax.  Ever since doing so I've had lots of problems, setting a custom font being my current problem:

```
var sText = "Hello world, this is some text that I'm going to try to format ok?"
var attText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sText)

var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16)]
attText.addAttributes(attrs, range: NSMakeRange(0, sText.characters.count))

lblLabel1.attributedText = attText
```

So this code crashes every time with an "unrecognized selector sent to instance".  Funny enough, setting other properties (like foreground color) work just fine... Just not fonts.  I've tried custom fonts, system fonts, other named fonts... nothing seems to work.  Anyone else run into this?  Is there something I'm doing wrong here???  This code works fine in XCode 7 and even legacy Swift in XCode 8

Thanks in advance...

James

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: If it crashes, what's the error message? It is an out of bound issue? If YES, I think that's an issue about how String counts characters, so try a `NSMakeRange(0, (sText as NSString).length)` or something similar? Also, if you want to set the same effect for the whole text, why don't you use the `NSMutableAttributedString` init method where you can pass the `attrs`?

Comment: Hi all, to clarify: "unrecognized selector sent to instance" is the error I'm getting.

Comment: Also, not sure why people are downvoting this question.  I know how to code, and this is definitely some type of bug.  Did anyone even try the code out in XCode 8 with a Swift 3 project?

Comment: I tried with swift 3 project and Xcode 8, posted a very well working answer to which you replied with same comment of crash, thats why I uploaded a sample on dropbox and edited my answer with a dropbox link, with exactly the same code that I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIFont(name:)` returns an Optional, so you have to unwrap it before use:

```
var sText = "Hello world, this is some text that I'm going to try to format ok?"
var attText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sText)
if let arial = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16) {
    var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: arial]
    attText.addAttributes(attrs, range: NSMakeRange(0, sText.characters.count))
    // ...
}
```

Comment: you are absolutely right buddy!  That was it.  Thanks for the help